# Why console monitor showing 3% CPU usage while the real usage is 0%?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The console monitor shows me the CPU usage is around 3%, but actually the instance is not in use. When I login the instance via SSH and use `htop` for checking CPU usage for a while, it keeps showing 0%.
Why console monitor showing 3% CPU usage while the real usage is 0%?

[CPU USAGE from console monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP0WW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have no active services running, the OS still has services running. This will most likely account for the missing 3%.

Comment: No one OS use 3% CPU all the time. And I have said, from the SSH side, the CPU usage keep 0% .

Comment: Your blanket statement that no OS use 3% would be nice to back up with some reference... And what OS are you using? And `ftop` does not seem like a very regular command to me. And google most likely measures the VM's use of real cpu while you measure inside the VM, two different things.

Comment: It's `htop`. Of course google measure the cpu usage in a different way, and that is why I asked this question.

Comment: From the Google cloud monitor, a newly installed instance keeps take 3% cpu usage. But I create a same sized instance from aws, the ec2 monitor shows only 0.1% cpu usage.